# Clarification in the definition of a metric connection

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

While going through some aspects of differential geometry from the book by Amari and Nagaoka on "Methods of information geometry", I came across the following definition for a metric connection:

[image]

Regarding the notation, $\mathcal{T}(S)$ denotes the set of all $C^{\infty}$ vector fields on the manifold $S$. While the right hand side of $(1.65)$ is a sum of two $C^{\infty}$ functions on $S$, the left hand side seems to be a vector field $Z$ multiplied by a $C^{\infty}$ function, resulting in vector field as a whole. This is clearly not possible.

Can anyone kindly help me parse $(1.65)$ correctly? In particular, I would like to know how to interpret the quantity on the left hand side of $(1.65)$.

Comment: The l.h.s. is the derivative of the function $p \mapsto \langle X_p, Y_p \rangle$ with respect to $Z$.

Comment: @Travis can you kindly provide a brief explanation for this? I am aware of what a directional derivative of a vector field along a tangent vector is (i.e., the covariant derivative), but I am quite unsure of what the derivative of a function with respect to a vector field is. Can you please explain it by taking $Z$ as one of the basis vectors $\partial_{i}$?

Comment: I think I can manage myself. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it. In case anyone else comes along and has the same question, $\partial_i f := \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ (or more precisely, $\frac{\partial (f \circ \phi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}$, where $\phi$ is the chart defining the coordinate frame $(\partial_j)$.